# Angular 4 router reload view when url queryParams change

Tags: angular

I have a component who shows a list of item than can be filtered using url queryParams, thos items are paginated from the api, and if a filter is set, i need to call the first page again, this first call is in the resolver of the router, so what I need is that the router reload in the same way as if I came from other URL.

**app.routes.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'applications',
        component: AppComponent,
        resolve: {
            data: AppResolve
        }
    },
]
```

---

**app.resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppResolve implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor() {}
   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
           // call to the api and the first 50 applications filtered by the url queryParams
    }
}
```

---

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private appService: AppService) {
        this.route.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
            // recive the first 50 applications
        })
    }

    loadMoreApps(): void {
        // call to the api for the next 50 applications filtered by the url queryParams
    }
}
```

---

**app.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    navigate(urlQueryParams: any): void {
        this.router.navigate(['/applications'], {queryParams: urlQueryParams});
    }
}
```

---

***other.component.ts***

```
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class OtherComponent {
    constructor(private appService: AppService) {}
    filterApps(): void {
        const filters = {
            'category': 'game',
            'author': 'username'
        }
        this.appService.navigate(filters)
    }
}
```

---

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: I already put the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the route set the property runGuardsAndResolvers to 'always' this way:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'applications',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: {
        data: AppResolve
    },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' // <----- This line
}
```

]

This will execute the resolve every time you access to the route.

Regards

Comment: The property name is runGuardsAndResolvers, anyway thanks you, I've spent a lot of time trying to do that.